# Problems with using col-md-push-*, col-md-push-*, or col-md-offset-* in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am a complete beginner to Bootstrap (**I am using Bootstrap 4**) and I'm having problems using col-*-push-* or even the pull or offset alternative.

Example: `col-md-push-9`, `col-md-pull-3` or `col-md-offset-3`. I have updated my browser and tried other browsers and it is still not working. I have added jquery, popper.js and bootstrap.css in the proper order. Classes like `col-md-3` or `col-x-9` work well. I'm failing to see what the problem is here.
Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3"></div>
</div>
```

When I apply the `col-md-push-9` to the first column and `col-md-pull-3` to the next column, I expect the columns to swap positions horizontally but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are no `push`/`pull` classes in Bootstrap 4.

Use the responsive `order` classes instead.

Example (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col order-md-last bg-warning">
            First in HTML, but last on 'md' screens and up
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Second and unordered
        </div>
        <div class="col order-md-first bg-light">
            3rd in HTML, but first on 'md' screens and up
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system-1

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes